# Plot points in a dataframe using WKT geometry field in R

Tags: r, gis, wkt

I'm trying to plot points in a data frame with WKT field.

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)

> head(df)
  id_pixel     id_lote                                        geo
1  1000013    10000131  POINT(-6421630.0792544 -3100141.21446612)
2  1000013    10000132 POINT(-6421398.42289614 -3100141.21446612)
3  1002031 10020311447 POINT(-6423017.27939664 -3120987.67242424)
4  1002031 10020311449 POINT(-6422093.39197093 -3121221.94306813)
5  1002031 10020311450 POINT(-6422785.09835309 -3121218.46519762)
6  6020361      602036           POINT(-5550130.276 -3814563.524)
> dim(df)
[1] 790381      3
```

I used readWKT from rgeos to transform WKT in coordinates and then plot the points

```
point.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df[1,3]), data=df[1,])

for (n in 2:dim(df)[[1]]) {
  point.sp <- rbind(point.sp, 
                    SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df[n,3]),data=df[n,]))
  print(n)
}
```

Even when this is working I have several issues to solve.

First, the for loop is working too slow. Since my dataframe has 790381 rows I need to make it faster. Is there any way to make this more eficient?? maybe using apply or other function? This is the most important question

Second, the coordinates I get are truncated. I didn't find anything about this in RGEOS WKT Functions documentation. It's possible to get the complete coordinates.

```
> point.sp
           coordinates id_pixel     id_lote                                        geo
1 (-6421630, -3100141)  1000013    10000131  POINT(-6421630.0792544 -3100141.21446612)
2 (-6421398, -3100141)  1000013    10000132 POINT(-6421398.42289614 -3100141.21446612)
3 (-6423017, -3120988)  1002031 10020311447 POINT(-6423017.27939664 -3120987.67242424)
4 (-6422093, -3121222)  1002031 10020311449 POINT(-6422093.39197093 -3121221.94306813)
5 (-6422785, -3121218)  1002031 10020311450 POINT(-6422785.09835309 -3121218.46519762)
6 (-5550130, -3814564)  6020361      602036           POINT(-5550130.276 -3814563.524)
7 (-5550362, -3814100)  6020362      602036           POINT(-5550361.932 -3814100.212)
8 (-5550362, -3814564)  6020363      602036           POINT(-5550361.932 -3814563.524)
```

Third, when I plot the points i can't manipulate points type or size. I get this warning message:

```
plot(point.sp, type="p" , lwd= 0.25,axes = 1,  col='orange')


Warning messages:
1: In axis(1, ...) : graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
2: In axis(2, ...) : graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
3: In title(...) : graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
```

[image]

So maybe I should use a complete different approach or could I make it work with a few ajustments?

Thanks! And sorry about my beautiful English...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quite late response. Using the `sf` package:

```
df <- data.frame(data = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 geo = c("POINT(-6421630.0792544 -3100141.21446612)",
                         "POINT(-6421398.42289614 -3100141.21446612)",
                         "POINT(-6423017.27939664 -3120987.67242424)")
)
df <- sf::st_as_sf(df, wkt = "geo")
plot(df, pch = 3, lwd = 0.25, axes = TRUE,  col = 'orange')
```

Gives

[image: point plot]